# Cannot resolve symbol 'ResultProfileBinding'

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

Good day,
I'm just upgrading my android studio to the latest version (3.6.1) and I'm just want to try the new features of version 3.6.1 which is the ViewBinding. I followed the setup instruction from this site https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable&utm_source=android-studio-3-6 but I don't know why I'm still having this error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'ResultProfileBinding'`

[image]

Here is what I've done. But still getting that cannot resolve symbol error.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My android studio 3.6.1 is the latest stable version that I've downloaded from the official website and the viewbinding feature is on the list of new features of this version so I am sure that I am missing something. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It's based on your layout file name. If your layout's filename is `activity_language.xml` then your binding class would be `ActivityLanguageBinding`.

Comment: Yes, it works! my mistake was I didn't read the first part of the page https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable&utm_source=android-studio-3-6#top_of_page which is they mention your answer.

Comment: everyone has who landed here was using ResultProfileBinding :-D

Comment: from the docs `The name of the binding class is generated by converting the name of the XML file to camel case and adding the word "Binding" to the end.`

Answer (score 1):

you can find the file in

project_dir/**app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Fragment layout file:
fragment_xyz.xml

The auto complete will do the rest for start typing XyzFragmentBinding...