# "Unresolved reference: ResultProfileBinding, Unresolved reference: binding, Unresolved reference: view"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       val view = binding.root setContentView(view)
```

"Unresolved reference: ResultProfileBinding, Unresolved reference: binding, Unresolved reference: view" I have no idea how fix these. please help me.

Comment: This is a great question, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478536/2388094